# Can you keep the height of a series of parent elements the same while letting the height of one of them with a clicked child element be adjusted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have a series of  elements enclosing a hidden form element each. Each form element along with its child elements have exactly the same class names assigned. Upon clicking a button in a  element, I want to only let the form element inside that  element show and the height of  element to be adjusted automatically while leaving the form elements in other  elements hidden so that the height of other  elements remain unchanged.

I tried targeting the form element enclosed in the same  element as the clicked  element using the eq() jQuery method.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <button onclick="query()">Show a form</button>
 <form class="commentForm">....</form>
</div>
<script>
function query(){
 var index = $(this).parent('.wrapper').index() - 1; 
 $('.wrapper').eq(index).children('.commentForm').css({
 "display" : "block"
 });
});
</script>
```

Upon clicking a button element, the form element shows and the height of its parent  element automatically changes to incorporate the form. However, at the same time the height of other  elements change to match the height of that  element even though their form elements are still hidden (!).

Apparently, the script is acting on other  elements even though the css of other  elements show display: none.

Please help me completely isolate the effect of the click event handle so the height of other  elements remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what vendorWrapper is or why you are using inline event handlers or what your css looks like, but maybe this example will help

```js
$(".query").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next('.commentForm').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
});
```

```css
.filler {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.commentForm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="query">Show a form</button>
  <form class="commentForm">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="query">Show a form</button>
  <form class="commentForm">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="query">Show a form</button>
  <form class="commentForm">
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected .vendor-wrapper to be .wrapper. Replacement of .children() with .next() ended up with the same results.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are mixing jQuery with vanilla JavaScript and misusing the `this` keyword. In an event listener, `this` will refer to the element that fired the event (the button in this case). Within a named function, `this` refers to the window object. Being that the window object has no parent with the class name "wrapper", your index variable will always return -2 (-1 for the fact that no element was found and then you subtract 1 from it). The easiest way to solve this is to use pure jQuery (or pure JavaScript) but either way you need to understand what `this` refers to

Comment: I don't know about vanilla JS, but saw some instances where console.log() returns -2. All the same console.log() returns the correct array index for each div.wrapper now.

Comment: I would be very surprised if that's true. Anyway - you can see in the snippet above how to do this in pure jQuery (adding a classname to the buttons, removing the inline event handler, adding the jQ click listener). That whole index thing is a very roundabout way of finding the form if it is the next element in the html which is why I got rid of it completely.

Comment: Thank you. For some weird reason, setting the height of div.wrapper to 100% fixed this. The cause of bug may have been that the min-height: 380px was set for div.wrapper and the script somehow messed up the height attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you only add this to your selector, example:

```
$(this,'.wrapper')
```

or try with this:

[image]

Comment: Chrome returns an error for $(this, '.wrapper').

 I found jQuery site's Category: Selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

However, selectors such as :first-of-type apparently don't allow the local variable to be passed, so I'm back to square one.